# Smart Watch Media Queries

Tags: media-queries, pebble-watch, samsung-galaxy-gear

The Pebble and Galaxy Gear devices have web browsers; what are some CSS media queries we can use to address screens of that size? Alternately, let's start a list of UA strings for smart watches.

Comment: Pebble doesn't really have a web browser. There is a JavaScript engine that runs on the connected phone and lets the watch communicate with the outside world, but there is no built-in way to browse the web on a Pebble.